# How to Fix DNN 5.2.3 Import error due to Permission table

Tags: import, dotnetnuke

### How to Fix DNN Import error due to Permission table.

Background:  It took me sometime to figure this out, and I wanted to post the solution in case someone else ran into this issue.

-

Trying to import a Dot Net Nuke v5.2.3 export file for a client. They are an enterprise/prof version and for our dev site we were using community edition.

I ran into this error when trying to do an import:

> Error parsing Portal TemplateViolation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'IX_FolderPermission'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.FolderPermission'. The duplicate key value is (18, 5, 9, ). The
>   statement has been terminated. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection
>   connection, CommandType commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(String
>   connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(String
>   connectionString, String spName, Object[] parameterValues) at
>   DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.AddFolderPermission(Int32 FolderID,
>   Int32 PermissionID, Int32 roleID, Boolean AllowAccess, Int32 UserID,
>   Int32 createdByUserID) at
>   DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.PermissionProvider.SaveFolderPermissions(FolderInfo
>   folder) at
>   DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.ParseFolderPermissions(XmlNodeList
>   nodeFolderPermissions, Int32 PortalId, FolderInfo folder) at
>   DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.ParseFolders(XmlNode
>   nodeFolders, Int32 PortalId) at
>   DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.ParseTemplate(Int32
>   PortalId, String TemplatePath, String TemplateFile, Int32
>   AdministratorId, PortalTemplateModuleAction mergeTabs, Boolean
>   IsNewPortal) at
>   DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalController.CreatePortal(String
>   PortalName, UserInfo objAdminUser, String Description, String
>   KeyWords, String TemplatePath, String TemplateFile, String
>   HomeDirectory, String PortalAlias, String ServerPath, String
>   ChildPath, Boolean IsChildPortal)

Comment: Can you make it clearer what the question is?

Comment: Sure the issue was trying to get the exported package to import properly on our dev server. When we ran the import process the error posted above is what happened

Comment: What I meant was, if someone was searching for this solution, what would be the question they are asking? You should edit your question to include that.

Comment: Good feedback, I updated it to give some more context. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the error was the new DNN (community version) install didn't have all the data it needed in the "Permission" Table.

When I looked at the new permissions table, I saw that it was missing all row that had an  ID greater than 7. To fix this error, we need to import the missing permission rows.

Two ways to fix this, (but do both before you try to do the import).

**Option 1:**

If you have access to a source of the exported site's database, you can run SQL command to import the rows you need.

New Database: DNN-NEW-DB
Source Database: DNN-SOURCE-DB

```
  INSERT INTO [DNN-NEW-DB].[dbo].[Permission]
  SELECT [PermissionCode]
        ,[ModuleDefID]
        ,[PermissionKey]
        ,[PermissionName]
        ,[ViewOrder]
        ,[CreatedByUserID]
        ,[CreatedOnDate],[LastModifiedByUserID],[LastModifiedOnDate]
   FROM [DNN-SOURCE-DB].[dbo].[Permission]
   WHERE[DNN-SOURCE-DB].[dbo].[Permission].[PermissionID] > 7
   ORDER BY permissionid
```

--

**Option 2:**

Is to manually import the missing records. I'm not sure if I got everything you need, let me know if I missed something:

```
INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_FOLDER', -1, 'DELETE', 'Can Delete', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_FOLDER', -1, 'ADD', 'Add', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_FOLDER', -1, 'COPY', 'Copy', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_FOLDER', -1, 'MANAGE', 'Manage', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'CONTENT', 'Content', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'ADD', 'Add', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'COPY', 'Copy', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'DELETE', 'Delete', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'EXPORT', 'Export', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'IMPORT', 'Import', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'MANAGE', 'Manage', 9999);

INSERT INTO Permission (PermissionCode, ModuleDefID, PermissionKey, PermissionName, ViewOrder)
    VALUES ('SYSTEM_TAB', -1, 'Navigate', 'Navigate', 9999);
```